# Swift how to sort array by doubles

Tags: arrays, sorting, swiftui

I am using sorted by and works although 12.05 comes before 2.29.  Is there a different approach that will resolve this?

```
ForEach(searchVM.landmarks.sorted(by: { $0.distanceAway < $1.distanceAway }), id: \.id) { landmark in
    NavigationLink {
       SearchDetailsView(landmark: landmark)
    } label: {
       SearchCellView(landmark: landmark)
  }
```

} //END:FOREACH

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `distanceAway` property is a `String`. So one solution is

```
searchVM.landmarks.sorted {
    Double($0.distanceAway) ?? 0 < Double($1.distanceAway) ?? 0
}
```

Note that `Double($0.distanceAway)` can return `nil` (if the string can't be parsed as a `Double`), so I have used `?? 0` to provide a default on each side of the `<` operator. You might want to handle such cases differently.

Note also that Malnati's is my favorite pizzeria.

Comment: Thanks Rob, much appreciated.  That did the trick and I agree Malnati's is our favorite as well.